# When perform sql insert?

Tags: delphi

I am using a VCL TCPServer components which fires events everytime a data is
received on a tcp port. Within the event data is available  into text 
parameter of the procedure. Because I want to save this data into mysql
database I am wondering which is the best approach to this problem.
Directly use an INSERT SQL command within the procedure for every data received
or store the data in a memory (i.e. TStrings) and then calling
a function every X (using Timer) minutes excute the INSERT command?

Thanks

Ok Sorry.

Comment: what are your expected numbers of events that require an insert? average and at peak times?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an answer to your question, but do consider the risk of your application failing (for any reason) between receiving the data and executing the `INSERT`.

If you use a local store of some kind as an intermediate to mitigate *this* risk, consider the risk of a crash while that store is being updated.

RDBMS vendors go to great lengths to ensure that data that has been accepted by successful completion of an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or similar command will not be lost or corrupted. Can you put in similar effort?

Generally speaking, if you are accepting data piecemeal rather than in bulk, I would probably keep an open connection to the database and insert data as you receive it, and only send an acknowledgement back to the consumer of your application once it has been pushed to the database.